# How can I extract all characters of a certain font from a PDF document using PDF Pig?

Tags: c#, pdfpig

I am trying to extract all the italicised words from a PDF document and write them into a string. At the moment I use PDF Pig, but I haven't found a way to check the font of a word/character. Is it possible at all, if so how, and if not, with which open source library can I realise this in C#?

So far I have tried to go through all the words of the string and check each one for the font, but I have not yet found a working method for this.